# How can I post php array values into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have followed phppots tutorial for a simple shopping cart.  Using the following code an aray is created and when action "add" happens I end up with values inside of the $_SESSION["cart-item"] aray.

```
<?php
$db_handle= new dbcontroller();
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) 
{
    switch($_GET["action"]) 
    {
        case "add":
            if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) 
            {
                $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
                $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"], 'image'=>$productByCode[0]["image"]));
                
                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) 
                {
                    if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) 
                    {
                        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) 
                        {
                                if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k) 
                                {
                                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) 
                                    {
                                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                                    }
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                                }
                        }
                    } else 
                    {
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                    }
                } else 
                {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                }
            }
        break;
        case "remove":
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) 
            {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) 
                {
                   
                    if($_GET["code"] == $_SESSION["cart_item"] [$k]['code'])
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);                  
              
                }
            }
        break;
        case "empty":
            unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
          
        break;
        case "Placeorder";
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) 
                {       
                    $insertOrder = $db_handle->runQuery("INSERT INTO `orders`(`Order ID`,`Order Date`) VALUES('$S','$Todaysdate')");
                    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item)
                   

                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]));      

                    
                    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
                        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
                        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
                            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
                        );
                    }                    
                    // Finally, destroy the session.
                    session_destroy();

                }  
        break;    
    }
}
?>
```

The "Place order" case effectively inserts data into a `orders` table, which works fine.  The problem is I also wish to insert array contents of $_SESSION["cart-item"] into a `order items` table.  I know I must either implode or multi row insert but am having trouble piecing together the code. The order items table column names are: Item Name, Item Code, Item Quantity, Item Price, Item Image and order ID.  Order ID is variable $S, which I have set up before hand.  I believe the code should be something like:

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart-item"] AS $item)
("INSERT into order items(`Item Name`, `Item Code`, `Item Quantity`, `Item Price`, `Item Image`, `Order ID`) VALUES($item['name'], $item['code'], $item['quantity'], $item['price'], $item['image'], '$S')");
```

I feel Im very close but can't piece it together.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would find it easier if you make use of paramaterised queries, and prepared statements. This would also fix the SQLi vulnerability in your code.

Comment: Looking this up thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the name of table is wrong, you use **order** in place of **orders**
use this:

foreach($_SESSION["cart-item"] AS $item)
("INSERT into orders items(`Item Name`, `Item Code`, `Item Quantity`, `Item Price`, `Item Image`, `Order ID`) VALUES($item['name'], $item['code'], $item['quantity'], $item['price'], $item['image'], '$S')");